# contact form ajax url= value????

Tags: magento-1.9

i have landing page in magento , i have ajax contact form but, i want take action contact form default! 
in url has contact_me.php but it doesn't work so could u help me what can i do?

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: "contact_me.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        name: name,
                        phone: phone,
                        email: email,
                        message: message
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function() {
                        // Success message
                        $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                        $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                            .append("</button>");
                        $('#success > .alert-success')
                            .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                        $('#success > .alert-success')
                            .append('</div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your **contact_me.php** located at ***magento application root folder***.

In,order to call `contact_me.php` from any page you need to change

to `url: "<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB).'contact_me.php' ;?>"`

**from**

```
url: "contact_me.php",
```